# cvs2svn conversion?

Tags: binary, cvs2svn

I converted my CVS repository into SVN repository.
It worked great, but one problem had occured....
I converted using a dumpfile, and the command was:

> cvs2svn –encoding=( ) –sort=(PATH TO sort.exe) --default-eol=native –dumpfile=PATH\name.svn_dump –svnadmin=(PATH TO SVN ADMIN) (PATH TO REP)

loading the dump file:

> svnadmin load PATH (to repository location) < PATH\name.svn_dump

Now some binary files, which in CVS are marked with -kb, have been corrupted. If I open both versions of a file in WinMerge, there look the same when the "Ignore Carriage Return Differences" is checked.

What seems to be the problem?
Did I miss something during the conversion?

thanks,
Oded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you used the `--default-eol=native` option, any binary files that were **not** marked as binary in CVS will be stored to Subversion in "native" EOL encoding and will typically have problems like you described when checked out of Subversion.  So, are you really sure that the files in question were marked as binary in CVS?

Please also note that there is a more proprietary CVS-like program called CVSNT whose repository format is different in several details to that of CVS.  For example, it stores file modes in a way that is incompatible with CVS.  cvs2svn [does **not** support converting CVSNT repositories](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/faq.html#cvsnt).  If your repository was ever touched by a CVSNT client, you might have difficulties with your conversion.  In that case, follow the tips in the above link and also consider setting the files in question to binary explicitly, for example using cvs2svn's `--auto-props` option.

Comment: thanks. I created an auto-props file and set each extesion as I wanted. It works perfectly. thank you.